# Mathematical notation to specify that a variable can reach a max value of $1$ and a min value of $0$

Tags: notation

How can I specify within a formula that the inserted values for different variables may only vary between $0$ and $1$?

Example: $x = y + z$, where the values used for $y$ and $z$ may take on any value between $0$ and $1$, but not outside this range.

I am looking for the mathematically correct notation for this. Probably one must make a case distinction here, but I am very unsure how to write this down.

Comment: You could just write $y, z \in [0,1] $. This means $y$ and $z$ lie in the closed interval between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this.  Here are a few options, but it's really a matter of taste.

1. $$x = y + z,\quad 0\le y,z\le1$$
2. \begin{align*}
   x &= y+z\\
   0 &\le y,z \le 1
   \end{align*}
3. \begin{align*}
   x &= y+z\\
   0&\le y \le 1\\
   0 &\le z\le 1
   \end{align*}
4. $$x = y+z,\quad y,z\in [0,1]$$

Answer (score 2):

This is presuming that $y$ and $z$ are real numbers.  You may specify it like this:

$$x = y + z$$
$$ y, z \in [0,1]$$

the LaTeX command is backslash in: `\in`.  It reads "is an element of".  Those brackets are not arbitrary.  the square bracket, '[' means "0 is included".  The other one ']' means "1 is included".  If you wanted to exclude either edge case you use round brackets:  $ x = y+ z$,   where $y, z \in (0,1]$ means "between 0 and 1 without 0 but including 1"

Comment: That formatting may be correct (I have no idea whether it is or not), but IMO it would be easier to understand if the first comma in the latex was replaced with a new line.

Comment: Fair point.  Perhaps a space would be helpful. I'll edit.